# Blank screen show in flutter web build

Tags: flutter, build, cors

I want to build web flutter, i use the command "flutter build web".
When I open index.file I get blank screen.

I delete the href from the file.

I open the devTools and saw an error CORS for font.Manifest.json :
(The file created when I do the build)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Flutter web generally has Cors problem because the "flutter run web" command is used default Cros configuration of the web browser. But you can change Cors policy when you run Flutter web.

You can run this command for disabled browser cors problems when you run development;

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"
```

Please Do Not Forget
Your client is not run this command when opening the browser self-computer. You must solve the Cors problem when you publish your app on the server. You must search the Cors policy for your web server configuration.

Generally, when I use the image source from assets I had this problem many times. And I changed my web server conf. and solved.

If you want more information about Cors problem of Flutter Web you can check this URL for it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/104935

Comment: If I don't have server ? for example, I also tried to create project and built it without changes and I get this error with blank screen

Comment: A new or older server is not important in this case. When you run Flutter web, it create a local server. And this server has cors settings and we can't change anything for that. But you can continue with the flag. When you run Flutter web with this --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security" flags it will work.

Comment: I add "--disable-web-security", and then build with "flutter build web", but I still get blank screen, with an error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at '.../build/web/assets/FontManifest.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.